# How to call a service using multiple Endpoint URIs

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, endpoint

To put into context, I have a client application that will attempt to call a webservice that will be deployed on multiple web servers. The URI list will be obtained from the `Settings.settings` file of the client and a foreach loop will cycle through the URIs until the available service responds.

Let's say I have a service with the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICMMSManagerService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServerInfo GetServerInfo(string systemNumber);
    }
```

In the web.config of the service's project, I have defined `CMMSManager` service with the the endpoint name: `BasicHttpBinding_IWorkloadMngrService`

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WorkloadMngr">
        <endpoint  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="CMMSManager">
        <endpoint  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWorkloadMngrService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <client>
      <remove contract="IMetadataExchange" name="sb" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
```

On the client side, I have the following code executed when the application starts:

```
private void QueryWebServiceUrls()
{
    var webServiceUrls = Properties.Settings.Default.WebServiceUrls;

    foreach (var webServiceUrl in webServiceUrls)
    {
        try
        {   
            var client = new CMMSManagerServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IWorkloadManagerService");
            client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(webServiceUrl),
                client.Endpoint.Address.Identity, client.Endpoint.Address.Headers);
            client.Open();
            var result = client.GetServerInfo("test");
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException e)
        {
            continue;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the application crashes with an `InvalidOperationException` when the `CMMSManagerServiceClient` class is instanciated.

> Could not find endpoint element with name
>   'BasicHttpBinding_IWorkloadMngrService' and contract
>   'ComClientService.ICMMSManagerService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this name could be found in the client element.

I have the following configuration in the app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/WorkloadMngr/CMMSManagerService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService"
          contract="ComClientService.ICMMSManagerService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I thought everything was valid by passing the `BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService` parameter to the  `CMMSManagerServiceClient` class. I have no clue what am I missing at the moment... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: there is no endpoint with the name `BasicHttpBinding_IWorkloadMngrService`. The app.config says the endpoint is called `BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService` so your code should be:

```
var client = new CMMSManagerServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICMMSManagerService");
```

Hope this helps.